# opencv and eigenface recognizer, python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I'm playing with openCV in python. I'd like to use the eigenface algorithm to guess who's in a picture.
I tried with

```
recognizer = cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
```

and it complains that

```
'module' object has no attribute 'createEigenFaceRecognizer'
```

I read around in the internet and found that the submodule 'face' should be used starting form openCV 3, but as I run

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
```

it complains with a

```
'module' object has no attribute 'face'
```

I'm puzzled..
Thanks
AC

edit - how I installed it:

```
1. download openCV from http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary
2. unpack to ~/opencv
3. download opencv_contrib from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib
4. unpack to ~/opencv/contrib
5. >cd ~/opencv
6. >mkdir tmp; cd tmp
7. >cmake -D -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv/contrib/modules  CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ~/opencv
8. >make -j5
9. >sudo make install
```

Comment: if relevant, here's the output of 'print cv2.getBuildInformation()'
http://pastebin.ca/3377555

Comment: Can you specify how you have installed `opencv`? Which OS you are using?

Comment: you need to update opencv to current master, then rebuild with [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) (please see readme there)

Comment: The same issue in Windows

Answer (score 0):

You might need to rebuild opencv together with extra modules as described here - [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib), if you didn't do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

7. > cmake -D -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH

that "-D" is the cause of the error